# add search field just above admin grid

Tags: magento2

i want to add search field here where records shows up

[image]

**grid.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Mycustomreport;
class Grid extends \Magento\Reports\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\AbstractGrid

{
    protected $_columnGroupBy = 'period';
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setCountTotals(true);
    }
    public function getResourceCollectionName()
    {
        return \Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Report\MyCustomReport\Collection::class;
    }
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'period',
            [
                'header' => __('Interval'),
                'index' => 'period',
                'sortable' => false,
                'period_type' => $this->getPeriodType(),
                'renderer' => \Magento\Reports\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Grid\Column\Renderer\Date::class,
                'totals_label' => __('Total'),
                'html_decorators' => ['nobr'],
                'header_css_class' => 'col-period',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-period'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'product_sku',
            [
                'header' => __('SKU'),
                'index' => 'product_sku',
                'type' => 'string',
                'sortable' => false,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-product',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-product'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'product_name',
            [
                'header' => __('Product'),
                'index' => 'product_name',
                'type' => 'string',
                'sortable' => false,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-product',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-product'
            ]
        );

        if ($this->getFilterData()->getStoreIds()) {
            $this->setStoreIds(explode(',', $this->getFilterData()->getStoreIds()));
        }

        $this->addColumn(
            'qty_ordered',
            [
                'header' => __('Order Quantity'),
                'index' => 'qty_ordered',
                'type' => 'number',
                'total' => 'sum',
                'sortable' => false,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-qty',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-qty'
            ]
        );


        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportMyCustomReportCsv', __('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportMyCustomReportExcel', __('Excel XML'));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Refresh\Collection">
        <plugin name="vendor_module_report_mycustomreport" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Refresh\Collection" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Reports\Controller\Adminhtml\Report\Statistics">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="reportTypes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="mycustomreport" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Report\MyCustomReport</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**note:- am not using ui component**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `grid.php` function `_construct()` with below code, It will add a filter on column top.

```
protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setCountTotals(true);
        $this->setFilterVisibility(true);
    }
```

Hope this help!

Comment: i cant believe this did the trick thanks a lot

Comment: @Pramod Welcome :)

Keep Kudos..!